# PDFBox split PDF, but with pages not sequencials

Tags: java, pdf, pdfbox

my question is simple, i have a PDF file with multiples pages, need to extract some pages(not sequencial Ej: page 1, page 5, page 10), and them put this pages in another PDF file, I read about that, but in some case split the origen PDF in diferents PDDocuments, but has to create some PDF file and them merge, en another case, split by pages, and add this pages into the final PDDocument, but in this case, the generate PDF give me error, have the 3 pages, but this is blank

Ej:

```
public void splitPdfFile() throws IOException{
    PDDocument salida = new PDDocument();
    /*Splitter splitter = new Splitter();
    List<PDDocument> documents = splitter.split(this.getDocument());
    Iterator<PDDocument> it = documents.iterator();
    while(it.hasNext()){
        PDDocument d = (PDDocument)it.next();
        System.out.println(d.getNumberOfPages());
    }*/
    int [] pages = {1, 3, 10};
    for(int p : pages){
        PDPage pa = (PDPage)this.getDocument().getPage(p);
        salida.addPage(pa);
    }
    salida.save("salida.pdf");
    salida.close();
}
```

could some one help me, thanks

Comment: What version are you using? If you try importPage instead of addPage, do you get better results? (Note that 2.0.2 has a bug in importPage that result PDFs get too big, so if it works, then use 2.0.1 until 2.0.3 gets out).

Comment: @TilmanHausherr, I do what you say, back to the 2.0.1 version, and change to importPage instead of addPage, and got the same result, it will be I have to change the way to do the split, like the lines comments in the example

Comment: I'd like to see the PDF file, source and destinations. Please upload them to a sharehoster. Please edit your question to explain what you mean with "the generate PDF give me error".

Comment: @TilmanHausherr the problem was the PDF file, I try with another PDF files, and was good, similarly, I still doubt about this PDF file with problems.

Comment: Some PDF files are really messed up, even if they display with Adobe Reader. But we can't find out without the file.

Comment: @TilmanHausherr thanks for your help, the worst was, I agreed to try which was bad :D.
Thanks for your help again (Y)

Comment: If you can't share the file, then I'd suggest you delete the question, to avoid orphans. You're of course welcome with further problems / questions if you have them in the future :-)